# Closing JInternalFrame added to JTabbedPane with MenuItem

Tags: java, swing

I want to close `JInternalFrame` with `MenuItem` close.I am writing code,`JInternalFrame` reference cannot access. How to solve this problem.
Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
public class CloseWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

JTextArea tx;
int i=0;
public CloseWindow() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    Crete = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    close = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    Crete.setText("Create");
    Crete.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            CreteActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(Crete);

    close.setText("Close");
    close.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            closeActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(close);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 427, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void CreteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("");
    i++;
    internalFrame.setName("Document"+i);
    internalFrame.setClosable(true);
    internalFrame.setSize(700, 700);
    tx = new JTextArea();
    internalFrame.add(tx);

    tPane.add(internalFrame);
    internalFrame.setSize(internalFrame.getMaximumSize());
    internalFrame.pack();
    internalFrame.setVisible(true);

     internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        tPane.remove(internalFrame);
    } 
});


}                                     

private void closeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                     

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new CloseWindow().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Crete;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem close;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tPane;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Whenever you need to access a component (or an instance of an arbitrary object) you have to keep a reference to it somewhere. BTW: an internalFrame is not meant to be added to anything but a JDesktopPane. And unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like kleopatra suggested, use a `JDesktopPane` to add your `JInternalFrame`s.

I made a very simple (and i hope) easy to understand example for you, i created a `JFrame` with one `JTabbedPane` on it which contains 2 Tabs with a `JPanel` conainting a `JDesktopPane`. By clicking on the `MenuItem` `addInternalFrame` a boolean value is checked and the "right" Desktop to add is choosen ;)

By clicking the removeInteralFrame `MenuItem` you remove the last added `JInternalFrame`.

Try it, maybe it will help you.

This is the MainFrame class

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JMenuItem addInternalFrame;
    JMenuItem removeInternalFrame;
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    JPanel tabPanel1;
    JPanel tabPanel2;
    JDesktopPane tabDesktopPane1;
    JDesktopPane tabDesktopPane2;
    boolean tab1Added = false;

    public MainFrame(final String title) {

        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tabbedPane = initComponents();
        this.setJMenuBar(initMenuBar());
        this.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JTabbedPane initComponents() {

        JTabbedPane jTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        tabDesktopPane1 = new JDesktopPane();
        tabDesktopPane2 = new JDesktopPane();
        tabPanel1 = new JPanel();
        tabPanel1.add(tabDesktopPane1);
        tabPanel2 = new JPanel();
        tabPanel2.add(tabDesktopPane2);

        jTabbedPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        jTabbedPane.addTab("Tab1", tabDesktopPane1);
        jTabbedPane.addTab("Tab2", tabDesktopPane2);

        return jTabbedPane;
    }

    private JMenuBar initMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        addInternalFrame = new JMenuItem("add new JInternalFrame");
        addInternalFrame.addActionListener(this);

        removeInternalFrame = new JMenuItem("remove InternalFrame");
        removeInternalFrame.addActionListener(this);

        fileMenu.add(addInternalFrame);
        fileMenu.add(removeInternalFrame);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        return menuBar;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(addInternalFrame)) {
            JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Internal Frame", true, true, true);
            internalFrame.setSize(new Dimension(250, 150));
            internalFrame.add(new JLabel("Demo with JInternalFrames"));
            internalFrame.setVisible(true);

            if(tab1Added) {
                tabDesktopPane2.add(internalFrame);
                tabbedPane.setSelectedComponent(tabDesktopPane2);
                tab1Added = !tab1Added;
            } else {
                tabDesktopPane1.add(internalFrame);
                tabbedPane.setSelectedComponent(tabDesktopPane1);
                tab1Added = !tab1Added;
            }
        }
        if(e.getSource().equals(removeInternalFrame)) {
            removeInternalFrame();
        }
    }

    private void removeInternalFrame() {
        if(tab1Added) {
            if(tabDesktopPane1.getComponentCount() <= 0) {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getParent(), "Sorry, there are no JInternalFrames anymore displayed on this Desktop!");
            } else {
                tabDesktopPane1.remove(tabDesktopPane1.getComponentCount()-1);
                tabbedPane.setSelectedComponent(tabDesktopPane1);
                tab1Added = !tab1Added;
            }

        } else {
            if(tabDesktopPane2.getComponentCount() <= 0) {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getParent(), "Sorry, there are no JInternalFrames anymore displayed on this Desktop!");
            } else {
                tabDesktopPane2.remove(tabDesktopPane2.getComponentCount()-1);
                tabbedPane.setSelectedComponent(tabDesktopPane2);
                tab1Added = !tab1Added;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And start the App

```
import de.professional_webworkx.jinternalframes.jinternalframesinjtabbedpane.frame.MainFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class App {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame("JTabbedPane");
            }
        });
    }
}
```